# How to show taxonomy name in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

I want show taxonomy name of specific ID. I tried with this code, but doesn't work.

```
<?php echo get_term_by('id','103', 'casestudies_category') ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query returns an object not actual data, see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_by/

You will need to access the name you need to use the following:

```
$term = get_term_by('id','103', 'casestudies_category');
echo $term->name;
```